# What to do if question details are found in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324141) question superficially ask about replacing '<' in a string, but after reading comments I know the root cause is just misuse of replace(). Should I help OP to move question details in comments to the question?

Comment: What would you move from the comments to the question? I can't see anything that would help clarify the question myself. Generally, if it will help improve the question, then yes move stuff from comments to the question and flag the comment as obsolete. But in this example, I'm not sure what you would move.

Comment: The question has now been put on hold. And that would be the general thing to do when you find a question that is about very trivial matters: they're almost always close-worthy, especially in tags for languages which have been around for ages. If not a duplicate then probably a simple typo.